# Apple Mac OS X & Chromecast AirPlay Mirroring

Tags: airplay, mirroring, chromecast

Is there a way to use [Chromecast](http://www.google.com/chrome/devices/chromecast/) same way as [Apple TV - Apple](http://www.apple.com/tv/) AirPlay Mirroring? I'd like to do display mirroring from OS X via [Chromecast](http://www.google.com/chrome/devices/chromecast/).